# Sorry, something went wrong using PHP Facebook SDK trying login to get via facebook working

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

I get the error every time I try to I use the loginUrl. I've done all the necessary things in facebook dev portal

```
<?php
session_start();
require( __DIR__.'/src/Facebook/autoload.php');

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => '{}', // Replace {app-id} with your app id
  'app_secret' => '{}',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5',
  ]);


$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
$permissions = ['email', 'user_posts']; // optional
$loginUrl    = $helper->getLoginUrl($callback, $permissions);
echo '<a href="' . $loginUrl . '">Log in with Facebook!</a>';
?>
```

Comment: App id and app secret need to be without the {} around them.

Answer (score 2):

Your `app_id` and `app_secret` shouldn't have `{}` around them. And it might not be the best idea to post your `app_secret` here.

So your code would be this:

```
<?php
session_start();
require( __DIR__.'/src/Facebook/autoload.php');

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => '119245818585909', // Replace {app-id} with your app id
  'app_secret' => '6a4bb23f0b6bc1c6b3f0cd6bf5e3239f',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5',
  ]);


$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
$permissions = ['email', 'user_posts']; // optional
$loginUrl    = $helper->getLoginUrl($callback, $permissions);
echo '<a href="' . $loginUrl . '">Log in with Facebook!</a>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. please make sure that App Domains in settings is start with http or htttps.
2. further make sure that Valid OAuth redirect URIs in "Facebook Login"